# I expect the Histogram to be showed in the range of min and max of my image value ,But it includes bigger values than max-value

Tags: java, histogram

I use Conrad open source and I want to compute the histogram of an image. For that first, I found the min and max of my image values and range=max-min and then the lower-limit and upper-bound exactly according to this link https://www2.southeastern.edu/Academics/Faculty/dgurney/Math241/StatTopics/HistGen.htm

Now my problem is that how can the program divide the range according to the bin-Width and how can I assign each image values to each bin-width(classes).

```
 public static int[] computeHistogram2D(Grid2D grid, int bins, int width, int heigth) {


    float val = 0;
    float max = -Float.MAX_VALUE;
    float min = Float.MAX_VALUE;

    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        for (int j = 0 ; j < heigth; j++) {
                val = grid.getAtIndex(i, j);
                if (val > max) {
                    max = val;
                }
                if (val < min) {
                    min = val;
                }
    }
}
    int[] histo = new int[bins];
    double[] histof = new double[bins];

    float range = max - min;
    float lowerLimit = range/(float)bins;
    float upperBound = range / (float) (bins -1);
    //float binWidth =( upperBound - lowerLimit)/bins;


    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        for (int j = 0 ; j < heigth; j++) {
                val = grid.getAtIndex(i, j);
                int b = (int) ((val - min) / upperBound);
                histo[b]++;
                histof[b]++;
                System.out.println(" intervals " + b );
            }
        }
    System.out.println("maxValgrid2D:  " +max + "   minValGrid2D:  " + min + "  binWidth  "+ upperBound);
    VisualizationUtil.createPlot(histof, "Histogram2D", "intensity", "count").show();
    return histo;

}
```

[This is what I got as a result,which seems to be wrong because the max-value of my pic is 21.12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfm5o.jpg)

[What I expect to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nd4IU.jpg)

Comment: where in this code are you using `max`?

Comment: @ScaryWombat What do you mean? I added the code here..  the max and min is always calculating right.

Comment: Does this code compile?  `float upperBaund` is not the same variable as `int b = (int) ((val - min) / upperBound);`

Comment: ya I just change it here because the dictation was wrong :) @ScaryWombat

Comment: what part of your code do you is setting the width of the graph? (if that is what your question is)  Maybe you should debug it

Comment: @ScaryWombat exacltly thats my problem, when I do it on a paper is very easy i would just add the width to each lower limit class to get the range for that class ... and then I can easily classify the value and assign them to the coorect class.. I dont know how can I do it with codes?!